# How to boot from cd or dvd on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, dvd

How can I boot from cd on Windows 8?
It seems a pretty easy question, but I really have this problem!
The boot order in the BIOS should be ok, I have CD/DVD, HD, and so on. In the same page on the BIOS I have an option to discover the optical drive to boot.

When I enter I don't see any optical drive. But when I boot, I mean when I power on the pc, I see that the BIOS sees the HD and the DVD but it does not boot from it. It just boots from the HD. I have also disabled the secure boot. I tried with many different bootable CDs and DVDs. What I am missing?

Comment: Did you set your first priority boot on CD/DVD?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I see that the BIOS sees the HD and the DVD"? The BIOS simply listing devices is in no way an indicator as to which devices are actually accessed while trying to boot.

Comment: @armin of course!

Comment: @DanielB I mean, when I power on the pc it detects the devices like hd cd and so on. But when I enter in the bios there is a page where I am able to set the boot priority, for example cd,hd etc. But in the same page I can choice which hd or which optical devices give the priority... well in this page I can't see any optical device.

Comment: I see. Although I don't want to trouble you too much, but can you provide a photo of said page where the optical drive is missing? Also, if you already have Windows 8 installed, you might be able use the advanced reboot menu (hold Shift while clicking Reboot) to select the desired boot device.